# Can composable functions call non-composable functions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I saw the new Jetpack Compose in Android and decided to check it out. I have been trying to understand some basic concepts about composables.
My question is: Can `composable functions` call `non-composable` functions?
I have searched Google to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is: Can composable functions call non-composable functions?

Yes. Pretty much everything in Kotlin winds up as a function call, and most functions available to you are non-composable.

Here is one of Google's bits of sample Compose UI code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NewsStory() {
    val image = imageResource(R.drawable.header)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        val imageModifier = Modifier
            .preferredHeight(180.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()

        Image(image, modifier = imageModifier,
                  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
        Spacer(Modifier.preferredHeight(16.dp))

        Text("A day in Shark Fin Cove")
        Text("Davenport, California")
        Text("December 2018")
    }
}
```

In that, the following functions are not `@Composable`:

- `imageResource()`
- `Modifier.padding()`
- `Modifier.preferredHeight()`
- `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`

The rule is that a function marked with `@Composable` needs to be called by another function marked as `@Composable` or one of a small family of end consumers of composable functions. This is reminiscent of coroutines, where `suspend` functions need to be called by other `suspend` functions or one of a small family of end consumers of `suspend` functions (e.g., coroutine builders like `launch()`).

Comment: Just a side question (purely opinion-based, ignore if you don't feel like answering): Is the emergence of Jetpack Compose going to be a problem for Android Java developers? Like is it going to eventually replace Android with Java? And would you advise a Java person like me to make the switch? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Quwaysim: "I just started learning Kotlin yesterday. I just decided to try Jetpack Composable for the fun of it." -- your enthusiasm is great! However, Jetpack Compose is still very new, and I would not recommend it to newcomers to Kotlin. "Is the emergence of Jetpack Compose going to be a problem for Android Java developers?" -- Android developers will need to learn Kotlin, much as how most iOS developers have needed to learn Swift and not rely solely on Objective-C.

Comment: @Quwaysim: "And would you advise a Java person like me to make the switch?" -- if you mean the switch to Kotlin, yes, you should learn Kotlin, IMHO ideally by the end of 2021. If you mean the switch to Jetpack Compose, while early adopters are welcome to play with it, IMHO most developers are safe to ignore it until it ships in stable form.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I really appreciate. Your answers are convincing enough :D.